# PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column violates not-null constraint

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, null, constraints

I am using PostgreSQL 8.4.13 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu on Debian 4.4.5-8, 64-bit.

I have created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
user_id     serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
name        varchar(200),
username    varchar(150),
password    varchar(150),
);
```

Then, using a Java application, I execute the following code:

```
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO USERS"
                + "(name, username, password) VALUES"
                + "(?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = DBCon.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
preparedStatement.setString(1, userInfo.get("name"));           
preparedStatement.setString(2, userInfo.get("username"));
preparedStatement.setString(3, userInfo.get("password")));
        
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

The issue is that `executeUpdate()` generates the following exception:

> ```
> ERROR: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
> ```

The weird thing is that if I execute the same insert statement using psql, it executes successfully. Why?

Comment: Why do you have 5 question marks and only 3 `setString`? Also they seem to be out of order...

Comment: You have too many question marks in your sql statement (specifying 3 columns but 5 bind parameters). Either add `id` as an insert column and remove a question mark or remove the extra question marks.

Comment: Thank you for your responses! The extra question marks and the out of order issue was a copy-paste error due to a modification of the code to present a simple version of it. I corrected it.

Comment: The error doesn't make sense unless someone is rewriting your SQL behind your back. What happens if you use `(user_id, name, username, password) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @mu commented, the error message contradicts the rest of your question.
The only reasonable explanation left is that you are, in fact, writing to a **different table**.

Try:

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id, name, username, password)
VALUES
  (1234,'foo', 'foo', 'foo')";
```

And check your table. Did the `INSERT` arrive at the table you expected? If not, check your settings:

- IP, port, db name?
- Same schema in the DB? Check your `search_path` setting.
- You did not by accident double quote the table name "USERS"? Double-quoted identifiers are not cast to lower case. Read the chapter [Identifiers and Key Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) for details..

Find the other instance of table `users` and fix potential damage you may have done. :)

Comment: Thank you very much Erwin! I was writing to the correct table. The problem was that I added the serial sequence to a different table (different schema). So, the table that the java application was writing to, had no serial sequence at the user_id column. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO USERS"
            + "(name, username, password) VALUES"
            + "(?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = DBCon.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
preparedStatement.setString(1, userInfo.get("name"));           
preparedStatement.setString(2, userInfo.get("username"));
preparedStatement.setString(3, userInfo.get("password")));

preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Note only three question marks and now the fields line up correctly.

Also don't worry about the `NOT NULL` constraint. It will handle itself (how could it ever be `NULL`, it's `SERIAL`) and could be causing your error. Just remove it.

Comment: Thank you for your responses! The extra question marks and the out of order issue was a copy-paste error due to a modification of the code to present a simple version of it. I corrected the code. The problem seems to be related to the auto increment column of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

The problem with me was that I was having 2 column in the database and in entity there was one mapped. it happened due to sql update in properties file

once remove one and get fixed