# INSERT with DEFAULT id doesn't work in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, insert, playframework, ebean

I tried running this statement in Postgres:

```
insert into field (id, name) values (DEFAULT, 'Me')
```

and I got this error:

```
ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

I ended up having to manually set the id. The problem with that is when my app inserts a record I get a duplicate key error. I am building a java app using Play framework and ebean ORM. So the entire schema is generated automatically by ebean. In this case, what is the best practice for inserting a record manually into my db?

Edit:
Here is how I'm creating my Field class

```
@Entity
public class Field {
    @id
    public Long id;
    public String name;
}
```

Edit:
I checked the field_seq sequence and it looks like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.field_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 START 1 CACHE 1;
```

Edit:
Here is the generated SQL in pgAdmin III:

```
CREATE TABLE field
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  created timestamp without time zone,
  modified timestamp without time zone,
  name character varying(255),
  enabled boolean,
  auto_set boolean,
  section character varying(17),
  input_type character varying(8),
  user_id bigint,
  CONSTRAINT pk_field PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_field_user_3 FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES account (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT ck_field_input_type CHECK (input_type::text = ANY (ARRAY['TEXT'::character varying, 'TEXTAREA'::character varying]::text[])),
  CONSTRAINT ck_field_section CHECK (section::text = ANY (ARRAY['MAIN_CONTACT_INFO'::character varying, 'PARTICIPANT_INFO'::character varying]::text[]))
);

CREATE INDEX ix_field_user_3
  ON field
  USING btree
  (user_id);
```

Comment: check this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372422/psqlexception-error-null-value-in-column-violates-not-null-constraint

Comment: That link is for a different problem

Comment: I ran your statement from pgAdmin III and get `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "/" LINE 1: /d field`

Comment: In the editor it shows default is empty for id.

Comment: I saw the / issue.  It gave me the same error for \.

Comment: Please show us the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the table in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

```
insert into field (id, name) values (nextval('field_seq'), "Me");
```

Answer (score 5):

There is **no column default defined** for `field.id`. Since the sequence `public.field_seq` seems to exist already (but is not attached to `field.id`) you can fix it with:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE field_seq OWNED BY field.id;

ALTER TABLE field
ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT (nextval('field_seq'::regclass));
```

Make sure the sequence isn't in use for something else, though.

It would be *much simpler* to create your table like this to begin with:

```
CREATE TABLE field
(
  id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
);
```

[Details on `serial` or `bigserial` in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)
Not sure how the the Play framework implements this.

Comment: I hope to find a better way of handling this than having to manually alter sequences for every table created by the ORM.  But this will be good if there is no other option.